# How do I query the last 30 days on CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm looking to retrieve records from the last 30 full days.

How would I be able to amend the `partitionID` below, so that it does not bring back any records past the 30 day mark?

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionID LIKE '%-2021-12-17%'`

Comment: my partitionID values look like this ```048-2021-08-25T01```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a column where you have the datetime in the ISO 8601 format, e.g.:

```json
{
    "id": "test",
    "partitionKey": "a",
    "date": "2021-11-01T20:36:17.1234567Z"
}
```

You can query using the [Date and time functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-date-time-functions):

```sql
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE DateTimeDiff("day", c.date, GetCurrentDateTime()) <= 30
```

If you wanted all the items within a certain time period (here for example all items in December 2021):

```sql
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.date >= '2021-12-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' AND c.date < '2021-12-31T00:00:00.0000000Z'
```

Comment: Excellent! would it work with SystemTime if the SystemTime has a value of ```2021-8-27 06:01:17```

Comment: It won't work with a value like that I think; the documentation says: "UTC date and time ISO 8601 string value in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffffffZ".

Comment: How about the range between the two dates? for example
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionID LIKE '%-2021-10-17%' >= '%-2021-12-17%'

Comment: @noobdev123 see the edit